# How to get values from child component?

Tags: react-native

I have multiple forms to submit, each form contains its values using useState.

```
const ProfileForm = props => {

const [values, setValues] = useState({
  form1: '',
  form2: '',
  form3: '',
})

const submit = () => {
   props.sendUserInfo(values)
}

return (
  <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Form1 />
    <Form2 />
    <Form3 />
  </View>
  </ScrollView>
)
}
```

Each forms look like this,

```
const Form1 = (props) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
      name: '',
      age: ''
  })
  
 ...
}
```

My question is, how to get values from three child components using setValues and submit it at same time.

Comment: We need more info about this, but basically you should send props to your components.

Comment: Why not use a Reducer ?

Comment: I am using Apollo Client, I don't want to use Redux in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got values by using useEffect.

```
const ProfileForm = props => {
   ...
    const onChange = (name,value) => {
         setValues({...values, name : value})
       }
   ...
     <Form1 onChange={onChange} name="form1">
```

inside Form1

```
  function Form1(props)  {
  const [value, setText] = React.useState('');
  ...
  React.useEffect(() => {
    props.onChange(props.name,value)
  },[value])
  ...
```

I am not sure this is good way but it worked.